# Customizing an icon breaks DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, icons

I have a DataGridView that displays a list of MMS Messages.  To differentiate between sent and received, I put a right arrow and left arrow in a column.  Our customer loved it, but wants the right arrow to be green for even more clarity, especially in international environments.

I took the right arrow and opened it in Visual Studio 2003 (I am using VS2010 for writing the application).  I recolored the icon and it looked great, however when I went to display the containing Control, I get the following error:

*The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:*

*System.ArgumentException:  Parameter is not valid.*
  *at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)*
  *at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.convertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)*
  *at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObjectInternal(Object value, Type targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)*
  *at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetFormattedValue(Object value, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewCellStyle& cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)*

*To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.*

When I create the DataTable to be populated with the data, I use this on the column that will have the icon

```
dt.Columns.Add(sDirection);
dt.Columns[sDirection].DataType = typeof(Byte[]);
```

When I add the data to the rows, I have a method to convert the Icon.

```
internal static Byte[] ConvertIconToByteArray(Icon pIcon) {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pIcon.Save(ms);
        return (ms.GetBuffer());
}
```

And I add the DataTable to the DataGridView with

```
grdMMSList.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

(Method calls removed from the above code for clarity)

I followed through in the debugger, and setting the DefaultView as the DataSource is where the error is getting thrown.  I tried placing it in a try/catch block so I could see the Exception, but it doesn't trigger the catch.

Just a few other bits of information:
-  The icon is stored as a Resource and is called by Properties.Resources.RightArrow
-  After changing the colors, I just Save the file in VS2003, nothing with a Save As.  The file still shows up as an Icon everywhere.
-  Back in VS2010, the Resource File does have the new color scheme and renders properly there.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not edit the images this way. If you want a valid set of arrows that are all supported for addition into a `DataGridView`, so to the directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033
```

here you will find a .zip file. Unzip it.

Then you will find varios subdirectories with loads of MS icon and images etc. Navigate to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033
    \VS2010ImageLibrary\VS2010ImageLibrary\Objects\png_format\WinVista
```

here you will find all different kinds of arrows in all different colours. My advice is use these, not your bitmap edits to existing files.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I had not realized those were in there.  My boss didn't mention those when he told me to go searching online for groups of Icons & Gifs.

I would still be interested in finding out why the edited image blew up when it was put into a DataGridView though.

Comment: What format was the image you attempted to edit? For a good icon/logo library, [see here](http://findicons.com/).

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond.  I don't remember exactly where I got the Icon set from.  I am using several out of a set, and they are all .ico format.

Comment: If you are doing allot of this kind of stuff, check out [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep an eye on it.  I'm not sure how much I'll need it, but knowing is half the battle!

Comment: So I want to understand what happened. When he edited the image he ended up with an invalid image. Or he replaced an .ico with some .png/.jpg/.bmp? I got the same exception but for a very different reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476488/datagridview-throwing-exception-in-default-error-dialog-due-to-datagridviewimage

Comment: BTW, it's very good to know the VS2010ImageLibrary in VS2010! Fortunately one of my colleague showed it back in 2008-2009. Those are all standard icons what the user will be familiar with.